# session.createQuery() is giving different result for same query string

Tags: java, hibernate

I am facing a strange issue. After 2 hours of debugging I came to know that my createQuery method is not populating `parametermetadata`.

Query is

```
SELECT count(tbl0.jobRowId) FROM com.tangoe.prime.batch.Job tbl0  LEFT JOIN tbl0.ftpDetails ftpDetails LEFT JOIN tbl0.jobTemplate jobTemplate LEFT JOIN tbl0.tenant tbl_tenant WHERE ((tbl0.name = :param_0) AND (tbl_tenant.shortName = :param_1 OR tbl_tenant.shortName IS NULL ))
```

In one module it giving following result

[image]

And in other module same query is giving

[image]

Comment: and create query method?

Comment: and "session" is what type?

Comment: org.hibernate.Session @NeilStockton